# Contacting remote server and testing with ACR880 gprs card reader

Tags: gsm, smartcard, gprs, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I know this is not a proper way to ask on stackoverflow but please try to understand me.Thanks.

Ok...i have orderd for an ACR880 card reader that supports GPRS as advised by the ACR company for use in my desired application to contact a remote server in places where there's no internet access(Any suggestions for a better card reader is welcome)

So my worry is;
will i be able to test this reader with a my local server to develop my back-end services to be accessed by the card reader through GPRS or i will require something like a sandbox hosted by the telecom company/network carrier.

Please correct me where am wrong and any advice or recommendations on what i need to know is welcome...Thank please.

Comment: Are you actually going to react or accept answers in any meaningful way, Hillary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is an ARM-based embedded Linux system. So regarding the hardware you are pretty much covered. What is at least as important is what kind of software and connections options are delivered with it. Unfortunately the data sheets do not specify what software this multi-function card reader comes with.

GPRS is a data connection protocol which supports the internet protocol (and thus TCP/IP and possibly HTTP(S)). So for the data transport you can use any normal internet connection. You should however make sure that your applications can handle intermittent transmission errors or lost transmissions. This is something your application should gracefully handle anyway, but the chances of encountering problems is obviously higher.

I don't see why you need a sandbox, but you should contact ACR to make sure you can develop your particular application. You may need a development toolkit.

Comment: so is it possible to access online services with this gprs reader in which i write say a server side application in say php to which the gprs reader can send requests to and get a response through gprs.

And can i host this php application on some domain where i can easily access it without involving any telecom company like i initially thought. 

Because it would require an APN configured with the reader...please help me clearly understand this. Thanks.

Comment: Am asking this because am i will b under testing and developing the server side with this gprs card reader.Am trying 2 figure out how it will b done...please help me understand this concept i have on mind and how to make it work, what i need to know and what i have to do...

Am sorry if i commented poorly, but please try to understand me here.

Thanks alot.

Comment: I'm not a consultant, Hillary - at least not on stackoverflow.

Comment: i just thought you could help out.Thanks anyway.At least i learn something from your comments

Comment: Your information has really help me understand what i needed to understand.Thanks alot.

Comment: Glad I could help you out Hillary